# How to retrieve only Thursday dates by passing any date in a week

Tags: postgresql

I need to get only Thursday dates when I pass any date in that week using built-in date functions in postgres. How?

Comment: Do you want to get the date of the same weeks thursday returned? That would be `SELECT date_trunc('week','2020-02-15'::date) + interval '4 days'`

Comment: @clamp you should post that as an answer rather than as a comment.

Comment: @Sentinel I thought the OP might want to clarify first. I added an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to get the date of the same weeks thursday returned? That would be:

```
SELECT date_trunc('week','2020-02-15'::date) + interval '4 days'
```

Comment: What must i do?  if i need the following future thursday to come ?

Comment: The thursday following what? Thursday following a given date? Or Thursday of the next week?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the EXTRACT( dow FROM date) function to get what day of the week a given date is and test if the result is a 4, which should be a thursday.

```
SELECT 
  days :: DATE,
  to_char(days,'Day'),
  EXTRACT(dow FROM days) as day_of_week
FROM generate_series ('2019-02-01', '2019-02-28', '1 day' :: interval ) AS days
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/functions-datetime.html